# sed command not working

Tags: regex, shell, sed

```
pushd tests
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_bindir}
for foo in $(make check-programs) ; do
 install -m 0755 .libs/$foo $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_bindir}
done
popd
```

sed command:

```
sed -i 's@for foo in $(make check-programs)@for foo in dristat drmstat@g'
```

o/p:

```
for foo in dristat drmstat$(make check-programs) ; do
```

expected:

```
for foo in dristat drmstat ;do
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make sure the quoting you're using is the one you have in this post. (Using `"` wouldn't work.)

Comment: i copied the whole code and o/p's....its exactly same as its posted here :-D

Comment: Then you must be using a funny shell - because with `bash`, what you've posted works on the file you posted as you expected, not as you observed.

Comment: i was trying to edit a src rpm's spec file using this sed command.....this command isnt working for .spec file,when i copied this code in new file and applied this sed command on it,it worked ..umm whats going on ,did u guys have any idea?

Comment: would the orig file you're trying to edit have been created on Windows? if so use `dos2unix troubleSomeFile` good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Re: *sed -i 's@for foo in $(make check-programs)@for foo in dristat drmstat@g'*

I suspect this is not your actual script. Did you have double quotes in the real one by any chance chance?

```
# as in:
sed -i "s@for foo in $(make check-programs)@for foo in dristat drmstat@g"
```

Now you have an unescaped command substitution: `$(make ...)`. Suppose that this runs in the environment where you are doing this sed job, and produces no output. The expansion of that argument is then:

```
s@for foo in @for foo in dristat drmstat@g
```

And that will produce:

```
for foo in dristat drmstat$(make check-programs) ; do
```

Comment: sed -i 's@for foo in $(make check-programs)@for foo in dristat drmstat@g' filename > filename2    it worked and i got correct result in file2...well thats strange

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take the data in file `file1`, then use this command:

```
cat file1|sed 's/\$\(make check-programs\)//g'
```

there is `\` between `$` and `(` and between `programs` and `)`

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't do it that way: `sed` can read files so there should be no use of `cat` (it's called UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`).